# InfoPath error while publishing the form to SharePoint list in Office 365

Tags: infopath, office-365, soap

I'm getting the below error when i publish the InfoPath form to SharePoint list in Office 365.

***Error:***

***The soap error indicates that an error occurred on the server:***

***Server was unable to process request. ---> Unsupported expression***

It didn't give any clear description of the error, so i'm getting confused and unable to resolve this issue. Due to this issue we are not able to make updates on the InfoPath form, it is really impacting our main solution. i have searched a lot about this, but i didn't get the resolution. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service which is being called from your Infopath form. Open in Infopath designer and check the .svc service which is being called. There can be several reason why the service is down. It can be due to lost connectivity of server or any change in account through which service is running.